# How to detect the player's position in a grid?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I’m working on a tactical RPG and I have an empty game object called Map which is composed by 36 tiles.

The Map object has this script attached to it:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GridMap : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject[] MyVector = new GameObject[36];
    public GameObject[,] GridMatrix = new GameObject[6,6];

    public GameObject Map;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Awake()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                MyVector[i] = Map.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject;
            }
            catch
            {
                print("Something is wrong!");
            }
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        int Counter = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            {
                GridMatrix[i, j] = MyVector[Counter];
                Counter;
            }
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

Each tile has this script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Tile : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool Current = false;
    public bool Selectable = false;

    public bool MouseOver = false;
    public bool Clicked = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    void OnMouseOver()
    {
        MouseOver = true;
        if (Clicked == false)
        {
            GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;

        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            Clicked = true;
            GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.green;


        }
    }

    void OnMouseExit()
    {
        MouseOver = false;
        Clicked = false;

        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.white;
    }


    private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Player")
        {
            GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.magenta;
            Current = true;

        }


    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.white;
        Current = false;

    }

}
```

I’d like to do detect in which tile the player is, for instace: if the player is in the tile whose position in the matrix is 0,0, I’d like to show in the console something like this: “The player is in the position 0,0’.

I’ve created this script and attached it to the player in order to get its position in the map(grid), however is not working:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GetPlayerPosition : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject mapgrid;
    GridMap map;



    float tileX, tileY;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

        mapgrid = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("map");
        map = mapgrid.GetComponent<GridMap>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            {
                Tile tile = map.GridMatrix[i, j].GetComponent<Tile>();

                if (tile.Current)
                {
                    tileX = i;
                    tileY = j;

                    Debug.Log(tileX);
                    Debug.Log(tileY);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

What could I do guys to solve this?
[Print of the project. The black cylinder is the player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVQ0A.jpg)

Comment: I would rather use `OnTriggerEnter` .. using `GetComponent` every frame is quite expensive... Can you define `however is not working` a bit further? .. as far as I can see it isn't doing anything except in `Start` ...

Comment: The script GetPlayerPostion is not doing anything. I thought that this line of code would work, but it didn't. `Tile tile = map.GridMatrix[i, j].GetComponent<Tile>();

                if (tile.Current)
                {
                    tileX = i;
                    tileY = j;

                    Debug.Log(tileX);
                    Debug.Log(tileY);
                }
            }` It shows the message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: See my answer .. the error is very probably due to the `Start` of `GetPlayerPosition` called **before** the `GridMap` ones so the array is not filled yet but has only `null` values. Also mentioned that in the asnwer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First I would make the type

   ```
   private Tile[] MayVector = new Tile[36];
   public Tile[,] GridMatrix = new Tile[6,6];
   ```

   so you can avoid all the expensive `GetComponent<Tile>` calls and make them only once.
2. I would also rather use `OnTriggerEnter` which is called only once instead of `OnTriggerStay` which is called every frame. And `OnMouseEnter` for the first part of your `OnMouseOver` since it is enough to set things only once.
3. Instead of using `GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag` and `GetComponent` I would also use [`FindObjectOfType`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html) or even better (if possible) reference everything already via the Inspector!
4. Also you should fill the `GridMatrix` array already in `Awake`. Otherwise the `Start` of `GetPlayerPosition` might be executed **before** the `Start` method of `GridMap` so trying to access the array at a moment when it wasn't filled yet and only contains `null` elements → **`NullReferenceException`**!

   My general thumb rule for `Awake` and `Start`:

   - `Awake`: Do everything that doesn't depend on others, set your own references and values, use `GetComponent` etc to find scene references
   - `Start`: Do things that depend on your references already being set. Like access fields of others etc.
5. Then I would make the whole thing more event driven and not make the player all the time loop through the tiles but rather let the tiles set the players position:

---

So something like

```
public class Tile : MonoBehaviour
{
    // maybe not needed anymore
    public bool Current = false;

    public bool Selectable = false;

    public bool MouseOver = false;
    public bool Clicked = false;

    // Will be assigned by the GridMap script
    // so every tile will know it's own position
    // you could also assign this via the Inspector
    // but maybe a lot overhead for 36 tiles ;)
    public Vector2Int TilePosition;

    // The player will register itself here
    // you could even already reference this via the Inspector
    // select all tiles and simply drag the player object here
    public GetPlayerPosition getPlayerPosition;

    // would even be better to already reference this via the Inspector
    // but maybe a bit overhead for 36 tiles 
    // except this is a prefab (what it probably should be ;) )
    [SerializeField] private Renderer renderer;

    private void Awake ()
    {
        // do this only once
        if(!renderer) renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    }

    private void OnMouseEnter()
    {
        // do this only once .. no need to do it every frame
        MouseOver = true;
        renderer.material.color = Color.red;
    }

    private void OnMouseOver()
    {
        // skip further API calls if already Clicked
        if(Clicked) return;

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            Clicked = true;
            renderer.material.color = Color.green;
       }
    }

    private void OnMouseExit()
    {
        MouseOver = false;
        Clicked = false;

        renderer.material.color = Color.white;
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        // do all these only once .. no need to do it every frame

        if(other.tag != "Player") return;

        renderer.material.color = Color.magenta;
        // Tell the player it's current position
        playerPosition.GridPosition = TilePosition;
        // probably not needed anymore
        Current = true;
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if(other.tag != "Player") return;

        renderer.material.color = Color.white;
        // probably not needed anymore
        Current = false;
    }
}
```

Then in the **GridMap** tell the `Tile` their position

```
public class GridMap : MonoBehaviour
{
    // just for clean coding reasons
    public const int GRID_WIDTH = 6;
    public const int GRID_HEIGHT = 6;

    public Transform Map;

    public Tile[,] GridMatrix = new Tile[GRID_WIDTH, GRID_HEIGHT];
    private Tile[] MyVector = new Tile[GRID_WIDTH * GRID_HEIGHT];

    // I would move it all to Awake
    //   1. it is possible so why wait until Start
    //   2. Makes also sure that the Start method of GetPlayerPosition
    //      will definitely be executed after all this
    //      => makes sure the array will actually be filled already! 
    private void Awake()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < GRID_WIDTH * GRID_HEIGHT; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                MyVector[i] = Map.GetChild(i).GetComponent<Tile>();
            }
            catch
            {
                print("Something is wrong!");
                return;
            }
        }

        for (var x = 0; x < GRID_WIDTH; x++)
        {
            for (var y = 0; y < GRID_HEIGHT; y++)
            {
                // This depends of course on how you arranged the tiles in the hierarchy
                GridMatrix[x, y] = MyVector[x * GRID_WIDTH + y];
                GridMatrix[x, y].TilePosition = new Vector2Int (x, y);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And now all that's left is the player having to register to the Tiles:

```
public class GetPlayerPosition : MonoBehaviour
{
    // would be better if you already reference this via the Inspector
    [SerilaizeField] private GridMap map;

    // Will be assigned when entering a Tile
    // since you want integer values I would also store them as such
    // and Vector2Int is already made for storing a value pair x and y ;)
    public Vector2Int GridPosition;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if(!map) map = FindObjectOfType<GridMap>();
    }

    private void Start()
    {  
        // if you don't have to know the indices within the loop
        // you can iterate a multidimensional array simply via foreach
        // because internally it is actually saved and treated as flat array
        foreach (var tile in map.GridMatrix)
        {
            tile.playerPosition = this;               
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @derHugo for your help. Now, it's working perfectly. Your explanation was awesome man. Explaining every step was really kind of you. Thank you so much again! I'm just in the beginning of programming and it's been a little bit hard for me to understand some concepts, but I try to do my best.